# How to access value outside of forEach in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
     GetMandatoryFieldsforUser: function (data) {
        var field = [];
        $.get("api/mapping/mandatoryfield?type=USER", function (data) {
            var self = this;
            self.dt = [];
            self.firmdata = JSON.parse(data.Data);
            console.log(self.firmdata);
            self.firmdata.forEach(function (item) {
                field.push(item.DisplayName);
            })
            console.log(field)   //able to print value                          
        })
        console.log(field) // not able to print value
       return MandatoryFields.User;
    },
```

> **EDIT**

```
 MandatoryFields = {
    User: field,        
}
```

my question here is i need to access field value outside forEach loop.How to achieve this using jquery or javascript

> **EDIT**

```
"api/mapping/mandatoryfield?type=USER" returns 

["First Name", "Last Name", "Location", "Email", "Password"],
```

see the edited question i want to use that field array inside MandatoryFields.User but if i use it its not showing the value

Comment: The problem is not with the forEach method. $.get() method is an asynchronous method. so the console.log(field) outside of the $.get() method is executed first, then only the callback of $.get() invoked.

Comment: thanks@BearNithi how to overcome this issue

Comment: @chethu Use jQuery.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and rely on its own "done" function to execute code AFTER data is retreived.

Comment: Please, provide the data returned from this request api/mapping/mandatoryfield?type=USER

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio check the response in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implements $.ajax:

```
GetMandatoryFieldsforUser: function (data) {
  var field = [];

  $.ajax({
    url: "api/mapping/mandatoryfield?type=USER"

  }).done(function(data) {
    // THIS PORTION IS EXECUTED AFTER DATA IS LOADED
    var self = this;
    self.dt = [];
    self.firmdata = JSON.parse(data.Data);
    console.log(self.firmdata);
    self.firmdata.forEach(function (item) {
      field.push(item.DisplayName);
    })
    console.log(field)

    /*
    USE return HERE!
    */
    return field; // OR SOMETHING ELSE

  })

  // THIS WON'T WORK, BECAUSE DATA IS RETRIEVED IN ASYNC!
  console.log(field) 
},
```

Comment: what you had written is same as mine its not working as expected

Comment: @chethu I read your latest post, and I edited my answer adding comments to clarify that you must process DATA retrieved by ajax inside the .done() section.

Comment: i got this but i want to use this field values in someother file if i return this inside ajax function it is not displaying those values in that file

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ajax method in jquery.

```
function GetMandatoryFieldsforUser( data)
    {
         var field= [];
         var scriptUrl = "api/mapping/mandatoryfield?type=USER";
         $.ajax({
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
               var self = this;
               self.dt = [];
               self.firmdata = JSON.parse(data.Data);
               console.log(self.firmdata);
               self.firmdata.forEach(function (item) {
                 field.push(item.DisplayName);
               })
               console.log(field) 
            } 
         });
         return field;
    }
```

Comment: WARNING: Using  async: false is definitely not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Since $.get() is an asynchronous method, you can use async/await to access the returned value from the $.get method's callback.

```
GetMandatoryFieldsforUser: async function (data) {
    var field = [];
    const returnedField = await $.get("api/mapping/mandatoryfield?type=USER", function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.dt = [];
        self.firmdata = JSON.parse(data.Data);
        console.log(self.firmdata);
        self.firmdata.forEach(function (item) {
            field.push(item.DisplayName);
        })
        console.log(field)   //able to print value
        return field;                          
    }).promise()

    console.log(returnedField) // not able to print value

},
```